# windows 7 sound stopped working out of nowhere

Tags: windows-7, audio

i have had windows 7 installed for a few months, working fine with soundblaster xi

around 7p was watching youtube videos with sound

went and made dinner

around 9p came back, realized there was no sound coming out of speakers, even though windows mixer shows sound output

restarted, no sound

uninstalled driver, restarted

had windows search for driver, it installed, windows mixer showed sound bar moving while playing an mp3 but couldn't hear

i've tested with speakers plugged into soundblaster, as well as headphones plugged into the audio port on the front of my computer.

what could have happened?  what could the solution be?

EDIT

wow, check out the crazy similarities between my post and this one:
(the solution didn't solve my issue)

[Why would sound suddenly stop working on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/56450/why-would-sound-suddenly-stop-working-on-windows-7/92957#92957)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like something may have happened to your speakers. To confirm, I'd recommend booting up a Linux distribution first such as [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/). If sound works on there, then your speakers are fine and something on your Windows 7 installation is the culprit.

If sound doesn't work on Ubuntu as well, check all of the connections for your speakers. I have some fussy electronics that won't work properly unless the jack is plugged in and turned a certain way.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I just had my sound fail a few minutes ago. In my audio tray it said that it was a digital output. The spiked while playing music, but no sound could be heard. The solution for me was simple.

After futzing around for awhile I decided to disable all audio devices, including the digital output that popped up. I then used windows to search for problems, It detected that the audio had been disabled and automatically enabled it. After that point, my audio setting read; Speakers, and under Controller Information:  High Definition Audio Device. After that my sound was working again.

Answer (score 0):

carefull with the ubuntu solution...

For some reasons I scrapped 2 sb cards .. were working fine in windoes, then install ubuntu, worked fine and then boom...  garbled sound in both Ubuntu and Windows, never could get the card to work after that

Answer (score -2):

Here is the solution -

- Go to <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- In run command type `services.msc`
- In Services find Windows audio endpoint builder

  - It might say it is started, but go ahead and restart it

This will take your sound services back on working